# What happens when a load balancer fails?

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, failover

Let's say I'm using Amazon's EC2 load balancer. I have it hooked up to two instances (excuse me if my terminology isn't correct). What happens if the load balancer fails? Do both instances fail to work now?

Comment: Stuff explodes.

Comment: Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typically load balancers are clustered together into a high-availability pair.

If one load balancer fails, the secondary picks up the failure and becomes active. They have a heartbeat link between them that monitors status.

If all load balancers fail (or are accidentally misconfigured), servers down-stream are knocked offline until the problem is resolved, or you manually route around them.

Comment: +1 I bet in general: Misconfiguration > Hardware + Software Failure

Answer (score 2):

Yes if the load balancer instances both fail the service is essentially dead.  Note that amazons uptime includes up to 4 hours of downtime a year (99.95%)